# Selenium click in specific element in a group of equals elements using nodejs

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to click in a element that have the same attributes of others elements.. How can I choose what element I will click after locate and check if it's enable?

```
<html>
    <body>
        Input 1 <input type="tel" class="myInput">
        <br><br>
        Input 2 <input type="tel" class="myInput">
        <br><br>
        Input 3 <input type="tel" class="myInput">
        <br><br>
        Input 4 <input type="tel" class="myInput">
    </body>
</html>
```

```
require('chromedriver');
require('log-timestamp');
const webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
const chrome = require("selenium-webdriver/chrome");

var until = webdriver.until;
var By = webdriver.By;

async function myMain(){

  let driver = new webdriver.Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();
  await driver.get('file:///C:/Users/myUser/Desktop/mypage.html');

  await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.className("myInput")),15000);
  let btn = driver.findElement(By.className("myInput"));    
  await driver.wait(until.elementIsEnabled(btn ,15000));
  await driver.findElement(By.className("myInput")).click();
};
myMain();
```

Comment: if you want to select 4th input, you can use xpath with index `//input[@class='myInput'][4]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to select 4th input, you can use xpath with index 4

`//input[@class='myInput'][4]`

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than one element in the DOM, iterate the elementResult array based on the position

```
var elementResult = new Array();
elementResult=[];
elementResult = driverdriver.findElements(By.className("myInput"));
```